# Find duplicated data inside Datatable using Select

Tags: c#, .net, select, plsql, datatable

I need some help on something.

I am reading some data from an Excel file and I need to insert it into an Oracle table.
Ok, but before inserting it i gotta do some validations.

The guy that did this before did the validations AFTER inserting. I am changing it to do it before 'cause it's an ammount of data that takes sometime to be inserted.

Here is the current way of validating it:

```
           SELECT FV, COD_BRICK, CANAL, SEGMENTO
             FROM TJANSSEN_MATRIZ_DDD_SEGMENTO
             WHERE (FV, COD_BRICK, CANAL, SEGMENTO) IN
             (SELECT FV, COD_BRICK, CANAL, SEGMENTO
                 FROM TJANSSEN_MATRIZ_DDD_SEGMENTO
                 GROUP BY FV, COD_BRICK, CANAL, SEGMENTO
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
             ORDER BY FV, COD_BRICK, CANAL, SEGMENTO;
```

If this returns something, then there is duplicated stuff and I should warn or give some error.

Anyway, I don't know exactly how to do this using Datatable's Select() method. I mean, I alredy used it sometimes but with simple expressions.

Thanks for reading and for your help.

dev_Gabriel (:

Comment: Can't you try DISTINCT keyword ?? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should do this in the most performant manner is to:

1. Import excel data into a temporary holding table in your database.
2. Run a query which pulls unique records between that holding table and your target table.
3. Insert those records into your target table.
4. delete everything out of your holding table.

Comment: Thanks, that's an option. I'll try it (: